# Tables in Bootstrap 4 with real width of columns

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, css-tables

I am trying to make something like this in Bootstrap 4, setting the columns of table in pixels, with fixed values, forcing the horizontal scroll inside the card, but is not working. The columns don't have the size I want. The columns sizes are going to be same for all devices.

```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
           <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body">
                   <table class="table-sm table-hover table-bordered text-center">
                       <thead>
                           <tr class="text-uppercase font-size-1">
                               <th width="500px" class="font-weight-medium"></th>
                               <th width="500px" class="font-weight-medium">produto</th>
                               <th width="500px" class="font-weight-medium">status</th>
                               <th width="500px" class="font-weight-medium">sku</th>
                               <th width="500px" class="font-weight-medium">preço</th>
                               <th width="500px" class="font-weight-medium">estoque</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                   </table>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `style="width:500px;min-width:500px;"` try that

Comment: Thanks so much, xNoJustice. It worked now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to be working here is the example code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table-sm table-hover table-bordered text-center">
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="text-uppercase font-size-1">
                        <th style="width:100px" class="font-weight-medium">first</th>
                        <th style="width:200px" class="font-weight-medium">produto</th>
                        <th style="width:300px" class="font-weight-medium">status</th>
                        <th style="width:400px" class="font-weight-medium">sku</th>
                        <th style="width:500px" class="font-weight-medium">preço</th>
                        <th style="width:600px" class="font-weight-medium">estoque</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also you could and `min-width` as suggested by @xNoJustice so that it will always set at least 500px

Comment: Sorry, but the last column doesn't seem to have 600px. Maybe is doing something proportional?

Comment: Adding to my comment, with 'min-width' worked :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put correct inline styles tag

```
<th style="width:500px;">
```

Comment: Hi rex, thanks for the anwser, but this also not worked.